# Can I programmatically detect changes in a sketch?

Tags: c, arduino, preprocessor-directive

At work we have an Arduino sketch that gets changed periodically. In a nutshell, it communicates back and forth on a Serial port. For the most part our software development team controls the code; however, there are some other teams at our company that periodically make last minute changes to the sketch in order to accommodate specific client needs.

This has obviously been quite problematic because it means we might have different versions of our sketch deployed in different places without realizing it. Our software developers are very good at using source control but the other teams are not quite so disciplined.

One idea that was proposed was hard-coding a version number, so that a certain serial command would respond by reporting back the predefined version number. The trouble however is that our other teams might likewise fail to have the discipline to update the version number if they decide to make other changes.

Obviously the best solution involves cutting off the other team from making updates, but assuming that isn't possible for office politics reasons, I was wondering if there's any way to programmatically "reflect" on an Arduino sketch. Obviously a sketch is going to take up a certain number of bytes, and that sketch file is going to have a unique file hash. I was thinking if there was some way to either get the byte count, the file hash, or the last modified time as a preprocessor directive that can be injected into code that would be ideal. Something like this:

```
// pseudocode
const String SKETCH_FILE_HASH = #filehash;
const int SKETCH_FILE_SIZE = #filesize;
const int SKETCH_LAST_UPDATED = #modified;
```

But that's about as far as my knowledge goes with this. Is there any way to write custom preprocessor directives, or macros, for Arduino code? Specifically ones that can examine the sketch file itself? Is that even possible? Or is there some way that already exists to programmatically track changes in one way or another?

Comment: Are you using [git](http://git-scm.com/) for your sketch?

Comment: Yes. That is to say the software developers are. But sometimes people not on the software development team get a hold of it and just change things locally.

Comment: Why don't you use a policy that allows the software team control the software entirely: have something like a pull request system. Nobody is allowed to use a modified version of the code unless it is "official" (i.e. from a central repository), and the only team which has access to that repo is the software team. If somebody wants to do a change, he has to make a pull request and get accepted by the software team. This way you get also the chance of a code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Risking an answer.

- `SKETCH_FILE_HASH` : you would have to precompute externally and pass as a flag.  I guess you're using the arduino IDE and this is not doable
- `SKETCH_FILE_SIZE`: same answer
- `SKETCH_LAST_UPDATED`: You can use `__TIME__` to get a string containing compilation time.

What I would do, taking into account the polititc parts.

- enmbed a keyword linked to your version control (e.g. `svn:id` for subversion, almost all VCS provide this)
- embed compilation time
- change the official build (the one the SW team controls) to use the actual toolchain and not the IDE and put it on a jenkins : you'll be able to use compilation flags!

embed a code like

```
#ifndef BUILD_TYPE
  #define BUILD_TYPE "Unsupported"
#endif
```

On your continuous build process, use `-DBUILD_TYPE="HEAD"` or `"Release"`

I'm sorry I don't see a magicx wand solving your solution. I'd invest a lot into training on why version control can save you (seems you already have the war stories)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this issue myself, and found this:

https://gist.github.com/jcw/1985789#file-bootcheck-ino

This is to look up the bootloader; but I'm thinking that something like this could be used for determining a signature of some sort for the code as a whole.

I did a quick experiment, where I added something like:

```
Serial.print("Other...");
Serial.println(CalculateChecksum(0, 2048));
```

in void setup(), and *was* able to get different values for the CRC, based on changing a tiny bit of code (a string).

This is not an explicit solution; I tried CalculateChecksum(0, 32767), and so on, and if I defined an integer like int a=101; and changed it to int a=102; the checksum was the same.  Only when I changed a string (i.e., add a space) did this value change.

I'm not crystal clear on the way memory is allocated in the Arduino; I do know there is program memory (32,256 bytes) and global variable memory (2048 bytes), so I'm sure there is some way of doing this.

In another experiment, I used the pgm_read_byte() function, and if I create a simple memory dump function:

```
void MemoryDump (word addr, word size) {
  word dataval = ~0;
  // prog_uint8_t* p = (prog_uint8_t*) addr;
  uint8_t* p = (uint8_t*) addr;
  for (word i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
    dataval = pgm_read_byte(p++);
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" ->");
    Serial.print(dataval,HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(dataval);
    Serial.print(" ");
    if(dataval>32)
    {
    Serial.print(char(dataval));
    }
    else
    {
    Serial.print("***");
    }
    Serial.print("\n");
    }
}
```

... and I put in a line like:
Serial.println(F("12345fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));

because the F() puts the string in program memory, you will see it there.

Reading the SRAM is a bit of an issue, as noted here:

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=220125.0

I'm not a compiler god, so I don't know how stuff like a=101; looks to the compiler/IDE, or why this doesn't look different to the program memory area.

One last note:

http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory

Those functions access SRAM, so perhaps, with a bit of tweaking, you could do a CRC on *that* memory, but it would seem a bit of an issue, since you have to be doing a computation with a variable... in SRAM!   But if the code was identical, even if doing a computation like that, it might be possible.  Again, I'm in deep water here, so if an AVR god has issue with this, please destroy this theory with an ugly fact!